# How do I resolve this shell script erroring out?

Tags: shell

So I'm creating a script to install a LAMP application it works very well for CentOS and Ubuntu, however in RHEL 8 it is exiting after each yum package that is installed and the output gives no reason as to why. If I check the package actually is installed and if I run the script again it will see that the package is already there do nothing and continue with the script. My script installs 4 things total and if you run it 4 times it will eventually complete.

I've tried running the installs with -q to quiet the output to see if that was triggering the error, I've attempted to set +e but it didn't work either. This is just a shell script using shell commands no special functions.

```
print_status "Updating packages with yum..."
exec_cmd "yum -y update > /dev/null 2>&1"

print_status "Installing the Apache web server..."
exec_cmd "yum -y install httpd > /dev/null 2>&1"

print_status "Installing PHP for Apache..."
exec_cmd "dnf -y install php php-mysqlnd php-mbstring php-opcache php-gd > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

It should just install and continue running down the line however. I instead receive and error that will state something like "bash: line 1: 1680 Aborted    (core dumped) yum -y update > /dev/null 2>&1
Error executing command, exiting". Depending on which package it is failing changes the number before "Aborted"

Comment: you need to include a tag (and description) of what language you are using that uses `print_status` and `exec_cmd` . Those are not normal shell cmds. If those are shell functions, you need to include the code for `exec_cmd`. Good luck.

Comment: I updated to reflect this is just a shell script calling shell commands.

Comment: What is `exec_cmd` ? `> /dev/null 2>&1` - maybe if you would enable printing errors you would see what's going on.

Comment: and of course, when I said "shell functions" , I meant user-defined shell functions. Search your files for `exec_cmd()` and then edit your Q to include the code defined there until there is a matching/closing `}` char. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe i'm being unclear here. I have -q off when I originally tested. I've  also piped out the output to a txt file and reviewed and there are no errors to speak of sans the one the shell script gets. The install happens and does complete with no issue when I run it again it records in the output that the package already exists and no shell script error occurs and it continues down the line.